# JS рекурсивный поиск\перебор по массиву объектов

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Подскажите пожалуйста, как рекурсивно пройтись по массиву и проверить что поля не совпадают?
То есть когда я присваиваю "mandatory" напримкр "3" объекту c id "5" -- нужно проверить что его id не равно mandalority, и что в массиве у объекта с id "3" mandatory не равно "5", и что у объекта с id "1" mandatory не равно "3" или "5", и так далее вглубь...

В этом примере если у первого объекта mandatory "5" - ошибка,
если у 3 объекта mandatory "5" - ошибка,
если у 4 объекта mandatory "5" или "3" - ошибка.

```js
[{
    id: 5,
    mandatory: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    mandatory: 3
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    mandatory: 1
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    mandatory: null
  },
]
```

Comment: Тут нет необходимости в рекурсии, нужен обычный цикл. Также, по описанию не понятно, по какой логике определяется ошибка... Т.е. если хочется присвоить mandatrity = 5, нужно проверить, чтобы нигде из всех объектов не было ни id=5, ни mandatority=5 ?

Comment: Тяжело объяснить...если если хочется присвоить mandatory = 5 обьекту с ID=10, то нужно проверить что у объкта с ID=5 нет mandatory = "10", но есть например "3", значит проверить что у об с ID=3 нет mandatory = "10" и mandatory = "5" и как далее...

Answer (score 0):

```js
let mandatoryEntry = arr.find(e => e.id === mandatory)
var endSearch = mandatoryEntry.mandatory === null
while (!endSearch) {
  if (mandatoryEntry.mandatory === id) {
    console.log(`Loop detected!!!`)
    return false
  }
  mandatoryEntry = arr.find(e => e.id === mandatoryEntry.mandatory)
  var endSearch = mandatoryEntry.mandatory === null
}
```